# Is there any different way to write a recursive function in PostgreSQL when you already know the other columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I basically have a few hundred rows of columns A and B.  Column C is meant to be equal to lag(C)*A+B.

But since recursive CTEs require you to operate in the form:

```
Select
Union
Select
```

I worked my way around it by numbering/keying/indexing columns A and B by row, and then having the recursive CTE keep track by joining when their key equaled the data's key.  But I realized this is incredibly inefficient if it is checking when the keys are equal, since there is only one match each time.  But even adding a limit 1 to a subquery is inefficient; why should it have to join at all?  It's always just the next row from the data.  Any tips or insight would be helpful.

Again, what I have is column A, B, a Row column, and C is meant to be the (previous C)*A+B

And my current solution is along the lines of:

```
with recursive CTE (row, C) as (
   select 0,0
   union all
   select row+1,C*data.A+data.B
   from CTE
   join data on data.row = CTE.row
   where CTE.row <= # of data.rows
)
```

Edit: For additional context, this is for blockchain analysis, and the task is finding the final balance of an account that accrues interest and has sporadic transfers in/out.  "A" is the interest rate multiplier, like 1.005, "B" is transfers in/out, positive, negative, often 0.  The balance is the "C" column i'm looking for, and just the last value.
The reason the final balance is not readily available from my data sources is that on the blockchain, data is only recorded on the transfers.  The interest rate updates in-between are separate.  I had to full join the data from A and B into a ledger that has every interest rate payment and transfer sequentially in time.  Now I'm trying to calculate the balance from that data in a more efficient way.

The site only allows postgresql but is here, the CTE in question is sOHMbalances: https://dune.xyz/queries/129943

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get? I'm not clear why you need a recursive CTE here

Comment: @Mureinik Added an edit with more context and the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the problem, I would expect the CTE to look like:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select a, b, a + b as c
      from data
      where row = 1
      union all
      select d.a, d.b, cte.c * d.a + d.b
      from data d join
           cte
           on d.row = cte.row + 1
    )
select *
from cte;
```

If `row` is not defined, you would need additional logic using `row_number()` to define it.

Comment: Yeah, in my implementation I do use row_number().  The logic you've described is pretty much what I already have except for a difference in the initial state.  I'm looking to see if it can even be done non-recursively or just in a less memory intensive way.